# AutoLayout Two Buttons either side of Centre

Tags: storyboard, autolayout

I'm struggling a little with autolayout. I have my main view and two buttons are on that. I want to place these buttons so that they will appear at an equal distance EITHER SIDE of the vertical centre, as shown below

Button 1     |     Button 2

But I'm unsure how to achieve this? I set the space between the two buttons to be constant and then set the buttons to be aligned centre but that just puts them over each other with the centre line going through the middle of the button.

I've even tried placing them in a separate UIView :/

Comment: I answered this here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735399/how-to-align-two-buttons-equidistance-from-the-centre-of-the-uiview/36326895#36326895](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735399/how-to-align-two-buttons-equidistance-from-the-centre-of-the-uiview/36326895#36326895)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you have two buttons next to each other.

Select them both and then move them left/right until the vertical center guideline between them appears.

Leaving them both selected, use the Align menu, and select "Horizontal Center in Container". This will make two orange vertical guidelines appear.

Still leaving them both selected, use the "Resolve Auto Layout issues" menu to selected "Update Constraints"

Done.

Nota Bene: you will still need to deal with the y-position.